# Ant keeps on showing console on JBoss server task

Tags: java, ant, jboss

I've started jboss server as an Ant task.JBOSS is getting started but instead of showing build successful,Ant keeps on showing the jboss console.It is not showing build successful.My build.xml is

```
<target>
<echo>"Start Jboss"</echo>
<exec executable="${JBOSSLOC}" spawn="false"> 
</exec>
<echo>| J B O S S S T A R T E D |</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: There is no need to shout when there is no fire. Edited your title and removed unnecessary capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new JBOSS instance in a new JVM.

```
<exec executable="${JBOSSLOC}" spawn="true">
```

Comment: When the spawn property is changed to "true",build successful occurs but jboss server doesn't get started.What should i do to start the server and make the build successful?

Comment: Ant is not the problem. It is jboss, is it not booting property. Have you tried either `failonerror` or `failifexecutionfails` options of the `exec` command. Try reading the ANT manual for further help.

Comment: Hi,I tried both with the failonerror and failifexecutionfails options of the exec command but they are not working.

Comment: I need a complete solution.Anyone please reply.